# Running project with Maven and difference between MANIFEST.MF over the years

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that was run few years back, now it needed to be fixed and run to jar one more time.
After running it with the same pom.xml problem occurs with accessing 'lib' folder that is containing all used libraries. I found the issue that MANIFEST.MF file is having not valid path to libraries used. For example:

- OLD: lib/nimbus-jose-jwt-3.1.2.jar
- NEW: lib/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/3.1.2/nimbus-jose-jwt-3.1.2.jar

When I manually navigate inside JAR file and replace new MANIFEST.MF with old one problem disappears, but this is more of a workaround then fix.

I am using InteliJ and 'package-f pom.xml'.
What is causing this path change and how I can revert it to proper stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.

I changed this part:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>com.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And added middle line:

```
...
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
<classpathLayoutType>simple</classpathLayoutType>
<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
...
```